# Performance on Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

```js
function preload() {
  this.load.image('background', 'images/table_en.png.webp');
  this.load.image('wheel', 'images/UpperWheel.png.webp');
  this.load.image('ball', 'images/ball.png.webp');

  roulette.circle.array.forEach(i => {
    this.load.image(`${i.index}`, i.src);
  });
  roulette.lever.array.forEach(i => {
    this.load.image(`${i.index}`, i.src)
  });
}

function update() {
  if (roulette.circle.previousCircle) {
    roulette.circle.previousCircle.destroy()
  }

  if (roulette.circle.previousLever) {
    roulette.circle.previousLever.destroy();
  }

  if (roulette.circle.currentStep === 100 && run) {
    ball.run = true;
  }

  let circle = this.add.image(108, 110, `circle${roulette.circle.currentStep}`).setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);
  let lever = this.add.image(200, 150, `lever${roulette.lever.currentStep}`).setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);

  roulette.circle.method();
  roulette.lever.method();
  roulette.circle.previousCircle = circle;
  roulette.circle.previousLever = lever;
}
```

I am writing roulette, where 359 pictures fall on a wheel (considering all its conditions). I uploaded all these pictures in the **preload function**, and in the **update function** I simply create the downloaded picture and delete the previous one. **All this affects productivity (because the speed of changing images can be different). How to solve this problem?**

Perhaps if i reduce the speed of the change of pictures, the problem would be solved, but I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update()` method is called once per frame. The default target frames per second (`fps`) in Phaser games is 60 - [API Reference](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.FPSConfig).

Many factors in your game can influence the actual `fps` that you'll see. If you leave it at default,  your `update()` method is being called approximately 60x per second. If you want the user to actually be able to see each image, this is probably not desired behavior.

You could lower the target `fps` number in your game config like this:

```
{ 
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  ...,
  fps: {
    target: 30 // 30x per second
  }
}
```

... but that can be imperfect. It is a global change to your game's update speed and there may be other things you want to happen 60x per second (like checking for input, etc.).

To change how often your images change without modifying your game's `fps`, consider creating a separate method to handle the destroy/create of images and reference that method inside `update()`.

```
function update() {
  if (!changingImage) {
    changingImage = true;
    changeImage();
  }
}

function changeImage() {
  if (roulette.circle.previousCircle) {
    roulette.circle.previousCircle.destroy()
  }

  if (roulette.circle.previousLever) {
    roulette.circle.previousLever.destroy();
  }

  if (roulette.circle.currentStep === 100 && run) {
    ball.run = true;
  }

  let circle = this.add.image(108, 110, `circle${roulette.circle.currentStep}`).setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);
  let lever = this.add.image(200, 150, `lever${roulette.lever.currentStep}`).setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);

  roulette.circle.method();
  roulette.lever.method();
  roulette.circle.previousCircle = circle;
  roulette.circle.previousLever = lever;

  changeImage = true;
}
```

If it's still happening too quickly, consider wrapping the `changeImage` boolean in a timeout to further delay how often your images get updated.

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    changingImage = true;
  }, 1000);
```